# New Fragment is not Opening

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

i'm trying to open a new fragment from recyclerview adapter
but when i click on the item ... my app crashes

i've tried some solution but they didn't work 
and i'm totally newbee in coding and android

here is my adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
public ImageLoader mImageLoader;

//List of superHeroes
List<ListOfData> superHeroes;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Context context) {
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListOfData superHero = superHeroes.get(position);


    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewName2.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
    //holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
    //holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
    //holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());

    //String powers = "";

   /* for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
        powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
    }*/

    //holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);


    holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BehindTheLayoutFragment fragment = new BehindTheLayoutFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
            //((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment).commit();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public NetworkImageView imageView1;
    public TextView textViewName1;
    public TextView textViewName2;
    public TextView textViewRank;
    public TextView textViewRealName;
    public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
    public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
    public TextView textViewPowers;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView1 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        textViewName1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);
        /* textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
        textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
        textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
        textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
        textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
        */
    }

}
```

}

here is the logcat

```
05-10 19:06:51.637 18514-18514/com.example.aninesoft.meltwishbeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.aninesoft.meltwishbeta, PID: 18514
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                    at com.aninesoft.meltwishbeta.RecyclerViewDataAdapter$1.onClick(RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java:83)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18437)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5413)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is the class where i called the adapter

```
public class Pants extends Fragment {

//Creating a List of superheroes

public Context context;
public List<ListOfData> listSuperHeroes;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager glm;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


public Pants() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tshirts_pants_shirts, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(
            R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));

    //Calling method to get data
    getData();
    return view;
}


private void getData() {
    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

    //Creating a json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ProductConfig.DATA_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ListOfData superHero = new ListOfData();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            superHero.setName(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_NAME));
            /*superHero.setRank(json.getInt(ProductConfig.TAG_RANK));
            superHero.setRealName(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_REAL_NAME));
            superHero.setCreatedBy(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_CREATED_BY));
            superHero.setFirstAppearance(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_FIRST_APPEARANCE));
            */

            ArrayList<String> powers = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(ProductConfig.TAG_POWERS);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                powers.add(((String) jsonArray.get(j)) + "\n");
            }
            superHero.setPowers(powers);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }
    adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(listSuperHeroes, context);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Initializing our superheroes list


}
```

}

Here is the xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/behind_the_layout_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:weightSum="100">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_men"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/mens_wear">

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_women"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/womens_wear">

            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_other"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">

            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can u post crash log?

Comment: yes .... wait a moment i'm posting it

Comment: done ..... you can check the logcat

Comment: which is line 83 in this code ?

Comment: this line "FragmentTransaction ft = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();"

Comment: i tried but unbale to use it ....

Comment: oh oh sorry, simply use context instead of ((AppCompatActivity)context)

Comment: already tried using context ..... but still got the same error 

actually i've tried many solution

Comment: I don't see any problems, in your code, can you post how you are calling the adapter from the activity/ fragment ? May be some problem there. May be correct context is not being passed

Comment: ok ..... i'm posting the fragment where i called the adapter

Comment: done ..... you can check that

Comment: Check my answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Pants` fragment I don't see that `context` is ever initialized. Simply use

`getActivity()` instead of context at all places in your `Pants Fragment`. Inside a fragment context can be found using `getActivity()` method.

Comment: so you are saying after chaning context to getactivity():

i would be able to use getActivity with getFragmentManager
like this

FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: No only inside fragment, not inside adapter

Comment: Inside adapter don't do any changes

Comment: @strangehacker Also see my comment on the other answer. context inside fragment can be found via getActivity() and inside Activity via ActivityName.this. For adapter you need to pass contxt as you are doing here. The only problem is context is never initialized so it is null.

Comment: What is it, post it, must be anotehr problem in the code !!

Comment: Process: com.example.aninesoft.meltwishbeta, PID: 22386
                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0068 (com.example.aninesoft.meltwishbeta:id/behind_the_layout_fragment) for fragment BehindTheLayoutFragment{42217c50 #0 id=0x7f0c0068}

Comment: This error simply states there is no behind_the_layout_fragment in your activity xml

Comment: which xml ? ??

the one i inflated with BehindTheViewHolder Fragment ??

Comment: XML of the activity to which Pants is attached

Comment: Its obvious as I said there is no behind_the_layout_fragment view inside the xml so it fails to find it. WHere is this view ?

Comment: that was not the pant xml 

see now i edited the xml

Comment: Dude it doesn't have the id too

Comment: what are you trying to say ??

Comment: let me explain ..... i wanted to open the BehindTheLayoutFragment 

not the the pant fragment .... and i properly inflated the layout in BehindTheLayoutFragment

Comment: Is there any view with the id behind_the_fragment_layout inside your activity xml? No !! For the transaction to work it should have it. I think you are confused about what             ft.replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment);
 does

Comment: maybe you are right .... but i still dont understand what are you saying 

can post some code and explain it ...

Comment: Oh, try it again then

Comment: i have the id ... see

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/behind_the_layout_fragment">

Comment: but the id is in the behind_the_layout_fragment xml

Comment: No, it is wrong then, you should first have a look at what ft.replace(R.id.behind_the_layout_fragment, fragment); exactly means. You have the id inside the fragment and you are telling the OS to put the fragment over the view which is indside the fragment. understand?

Comment: Just like sending an aeroplane to the pilot seat instead of some place :D

Comment: hahahah 
so what to do ???

i give the id to pant xml 
and now click is not working

but finally no error ^_^

Comment: Not even pant xml, since you are using getFragmentManager the id should be inside activity xml. If you want the id to be in pant xml then use getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: getChildFragmentManager not availble and when i put the id to acvity xml nothing changed ... still getting the same error

Comment: I guess what mistake you are making. You need to wrap the view inside a frame layout then name the id of the frame layout as behind_the_layout_fragment. You can only place a fragment over a frame layout

Comment: The xml that you have posted with the frame layout, this is the activity xml right? Because last xml that you psted was looking much different

Comment: Hmm, I will need to put more time in that case, you should look at how transaction works exactly. might be some silly mistake though I don't see one. You may also try posting it as a new question.

Answer (score -1):

use this
 FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: He is inside the adapter when calling FragmentTransaction and getActivity() doesn't return context inside adapter. It does so inside fragment.

Comment: unable to use getActivity();