# Get Retrofit data. Android. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am new to programming and I need your help.
The task is this: I make a request from the service where I want to get the character's id, but it doesn't work. Below is the code!

**Api**

```
@GET("people/{id}")
    suspend fun getCharacter(@Path("id") id: Int): Response<Characters>
```

**Repository**

```
suspend fun getCharacters(id: Int) =
        RetrofitBuilder.api.getCharacter(id)
```

**Viewmodel**

```
class DetailViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var repository = StarWarsRepository()
    private val _response = MutableLiveData<Characters>()
    val character: LiveData<Characters>
        get() = _response


    fun getCharacter(id: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getCharacters(id).let { response ->

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    _response.postValue(response.body())
                } else {
                    Log.d("tag", "Error: ${response.code()}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**
In line 27 I call the function
getCharacterViewModel()
and there you need to specify id. What do I need to specify in this parameter so that when I click on a character in the list, I have information about him?

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentDetailBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var viewModel: DetailViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[(DetailViewModel::class.java)]
        getCharacterViewModel()
        return view
    }

    private fun getCharacterViewModel(id: Int){
        viewModel.getCharacter(id)
        viewModel.character.observe(this, { name ->
            binding.birth.text = name.birth_year
            binding.name.text = name.characters
            binding.mass.text = name.mass
            binding.mass.text = name.height

        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to click on an Item that's on one list and get info about the item, right?

You'll need to work on the list. Is it a RecyclerView? For example, if your list is a RecyclerView, you'll need to modify your adapter.

Create on more param on your adapter

```
class YourAdapter (..., val onItemClick: (Character) -> Unit){
   //Your Code Here
}
```

And, on "onBind" method on your adapter, set the click listener on your view and call

```
onItemClick(<clickedItemHereAsParam>))
```

within it.

Check this anwser with more details:
[How do I implement onClickListener to a recyclerView to open a new fragment when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886457/how-do-i-implement-onclicklistener-to-a-recyclerview-to-open-a-new-fragment-when/70886570#70886570)

Comment: Yes, I made a click handler and it goes to another fragment. But the problem is that in OnCreateView getCharacterViewModel(3)
and my character opens everywhere under id 3. but I need that when I click on each character, information about him opens.